# Polynomial interpolation of binary word signal

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory

Let consider a binary word $x_1 \ldots x_n$ (finite sequence of elements of $\{0,1\}$.

I want to construct a polynomial $P$ that interpolates the points $(i, x_i)$ for $i \in \{1\ldots n\}$ , such that:

- $P(x) \neq 0,1 $ for all $x \in [0,n]$ and $x \neq 1,\ldots n$
- $P(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x \in [0,n]$
- $\deg P = \mathcal{O} (e^n)$

In a word, P interpolates the word and is contained in $(0,1)$ at the non-integers points (and can of course do anything outside $[0,n]$).

I was thinking to approximate a $C^\infty$ function that does the job - and of course interpolate the considered points, but I've not managed to control the polynomial in order not to get greater than 1 (or lower than 0).

It seems possible to do it with splines but I am looking for a polynomial.

Comment: If $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $$x_j:=\begin{cases} 1 & j=i\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ an ansatz is $$P(x)=\prod_{j\neq i} \left(\frac{x-j}{i-j} \right)^2\left(2- \frac{x-j}{i-j} \right)^2.$$ At least this function has the property that it interpolates and it is local minima or maxima at integers. The other case can maybe done by superposition and different exponents.

Comment: More generally you can choose $$P(x):=\prod_{j\neq i} p\left(\frac{x-j}{i-j}\right)$$ where $p$ is any polynomial with $p(0)=0$, $p(1)=1$, $p'(0)=0$ $p'(1)=0$ and $p(x)\in [-1,1]$ for all $x\in [-n,n]$.

Comment: @user35593: I do not think that $p(x)=x^2(2-x)^2$ satisfies your conditions if $n$ is large...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This was just an idea. I think for every $n$ it should be possible to find a polynomial which satisfies the conditions above. However I don't have an explicit expression for such a polynomial nor do I no how to control the degree...

Comment: Yes you can recover what is needed by tweaking these kind of polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a related question:
[Finite interpolation by a nondecreasing polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16673/finite-interpolation-by-a-nondecreasing-polynomial) with a satisfactory answer. The last two papers cited there allow to find the required polynomial.

The results of the first paper

[E. Passow, L. Raymon, "The degree of piecewise monotone interpolation"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2040274)

allow to obtain a polynomial of exponential degree (although the base of the exponent seems to be larger than $e$, when we apply it directly). I do not provide the details, in view of what follows. **EDIT.** The results of this paper, however, may also be applied in what follows; see next edit.

The second paper,

[G.L Iliev, "Exact estimates for monotone interpolation"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904580900829#),

seems to allow even polynomial bound for the degree in your special case. It suffices to apply the following trick.

Take the Chebyshev polynomial, say $T_{1000n}(x)$. It alternately attains the values $\pm1$ at known points. The polynomial $Q(x)=(T_{1000n}(x)+1)/2$ alternatively attains $0$ and $1$, and its values are in $[0,1]$. Now choose some points $0=a_0<a_1<\dots<a_n<1$ with $Q(a_i)=x_i$ ($i=1,2,\dots,n$), so that $A=\max|a_i-a_{i-1}|$ and $B=\min|a_i-a_{i-1}|$ differ by factor of less than, say, 1000. It is clearly possible, if we choose them in a greedy way. As a result, $Q(a_i)=x_i$, and the values of $Q$ on $[a_0,a_n]$ lie in $[0,1]$.

Now we have two problems: (1) the points $a_i$ are not distributed uniformly, and (2) there are other points on $[a_0,a_n]$ where $Q$ attains $0$ or $1$. We start with (2), then resolving (1).

(2) is easily curable in the following way: we may add to $Q$ a polynomial of the form 
$$
  \delta Q(x)=\varepsilon\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)^2\cdot \prod_j(x-b_j),
$$ 
where $b_j$ are chosen so that $\delta Q(x)$ is positive around $a_i$ if $x_i=0$ and negative if $x_i=1$. If $b_j$ are chosen appropriately, and $\varepsilon$ is small enough, then the values of $R(x)=Q(x)+\delta Q(x)$ on $[a_0,a_n]$ are still on $[0,1]$, but $R$ attains the values $0,1$ exactly at $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

We are left with (1). Now, we apply the result of the aforementioned paper by Iliev in order to find a polynomial $S(x)$ which is monotonous on $[0,1]$ and satisfies $S(i/n)=a_i$. Its degree is bounded as
$$
  \deg S\leq cn\ln\left(e+A/B\right)
$$
for some absolute constant $c$, thus by a linear function in $n$. **EDIT.** As Iliev claims, the first cited paper also provides linear degree of a polynomial in the monotonic case, namely $\leq c'nA/B$; sorry, I haven't checked this yet.

Finally, the polynomial $R(S(nx))$ does the job.